# Xamarin.Forms app crashes after update

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have checked all the questions raised in SO like this and i couldn't find answer to my issue.

We had an app in PlayStore which is developed in Xamarin.Android with code shared with Xamarin.iOS via Shared Project.

Now we are switching to Xamarin.Forms. We have changed ,
Some UI
Login mechanism with AutoLogin based on Token stored in local device.

The app working fine in Devices and Simulators.

We have uploaded our app to playstore. If the user have old version in their device, after update the app crashing after showing splashscreen for few seconds.
If we uninstall the old version, it is working fine.

Error in google console:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException:

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2955)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java030)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1696)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)

at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java27)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:

at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getLong (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:279)

at md56c96bd185bfbb3ebebdd94ef17444e8f.MainActivity.n_onCreate (Native Method)

at md56c96bd185bfbb3ebebdd94ef17444e8f.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java1)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7174)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1220)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2908)
```

We are not sure why this is happening. Can any one let me know, why this happening and how to prevent it. Also, is it possible reproduce this issue in VisualStudio?

Thanks

Comment: this is known bug in xamarin forms and there are many other SO posts for the same have you tried all of them?

Comment: @g.hakim yes tried most of them.. can you please share any official link, where it states as known bug??

Comment: @WPFUser what happens if you install the debug version instead of the release version ?!

Comment: @WPFUser Check your Application properties, that you probably use in your autologin mechanism.

Comment: @toumir installing via vs working fine. Issue happening only while updating from PlayStore. i cannot publish debug version in playstore. Is that you;re asking?

Comment: @ДенисЧорный you mean i have to change them?

Comment: @WPFUser yes this what I mean but loccaly not from PlayStore, like that you can install/update the with the debug Version

Comment: @WPFUser I think you need to add a mechanism that can rewrite your properties. Get app's properties using `App.Current.Properties.TryGetValue`, if it has them, then rewrite using `App.Current.Properties["your_property"] = ...`, or create new `App.Current.Properties.Add("your_property", "default_value")`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your SharedPreferences parameters have incompatible types. And I didn't found a proof that it could be xamarin.Forms problem. If you look at the source code [SharedPreferencesImpl.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/1aa0d01cc859ba0a99e373759fab634f0ae9b17a/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java) to the getLong method you will see the following cast:

```
Long v = (Long)mMap.get(key);
```

This means that on old versions there was parameter with the same name but with type different from Long. You read this parameter in onCreate method of your MainActivity, but parameter type is incompatible.

Comment: i will check it and let you know